# How to remove certain words only if it is additional keyword

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
id  keyword
1   transfer
2   atm transfer
3   atm
4   ulta transfer
```

I want to delete `transfer` word if no one words left, but if only `transfer` word left, the word is still remain, other word is `atm`, but if only `atm`  and `transfer` left, we select `atm`

My expected output

```
id  keyword       keyword_2
1   transfer      transfer
2   atm transfer  atm
3   atm           atm
4   ulta transfer ulta
```

Hopefully, this question is clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) only applied for filtered values by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['keyword_2'] = df['keyword'].mask(df['keyword'] != 'transfer', 
                                     df['keyword'].str.replace('transfer', '').str.strip())
print (df)
   id        keyword keyword_2
0   1       transfer  transfer
1   2   atm transfer       atm
2   3            atm       atm
3   4  ulta transfer      ulta
```

Another solution with no strip, but with `join` and `split`:

```
print (df)
   id          keyword
0   1         transfer
1   2     atm transfer
2   3              atm
3   4  ulta transfer v

df['keyword_2'] = [' '.join(y for y in x.split() if y != 'transfer') 
                         if x != 'transfer' else x for x in df['keyword']]

print (df)
   id          keyword keyword_2
0   1         transfer  transfer
1   2     atm transfer       atm
2   3              atm       atm
3   4  ulta transfer v    ulta v
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d['keyword'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('transfer','') if len(x.split(' ')) > 1 else x )
```

**output**

```
0    transfer
1        atm 
2         atm
3       ulta 
Name: keyword, dtype: object
```